# Unifi specific SFP adapters?

Tags: cisco, sfp, unifi

I have a few 10GbE SFP+ devices with Cisco plugs. I need to upgrade my network and am considering a switch from Unifi. Does anyone know if they play well with SFP+ plugs from other brands?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ubiquiti has [a list](https://help.ui.com/hc/en-us/articles/212561258-UniFi-USW-Which-SFP-Modules-Can-be-Used) of hardware that has been tested to work, but note that they cannot provide official support for anything but their own modules. There are several Cisco SFP+ models on the list.

You can also [search the forum](https://community.ui.com/questions) for the model numbers of the SFP+ modules you have (and post your own question if you don't see them already listed).